# "Fall Tür" meaning

Tags: meaning

What does "**Fall tür**" mean?

I'm reading a fairy tale from [https://www.ndr.de](https://www.ndr.de/fernsehen/barrierefreie_angebote/leichte_sprache/Die-3-Federn,dreifedernleichtesprache100.html) and I don't understand that part. The only thing I can think of is "a fallen door". But I'm not sure.

The context:

Ein Sohn folgt der Feder nach Osten.
Ein Sohn folgt der Feder nach Westen.
Nur der Dummling muss bei der 3. Feder bleiben.
Deshalb lachen seine Brüder über den Dummling.
Der Dummling setzt sich hin.
Und ist traurig.
Plötzlich sieht der Dummling:
Neben der Feder ist eine Fall∙tür.
Die Fall∙tür ist im Boden.
Der Dummling öffnet die Fall∙tür.
Unter der Fall∙tür ist eine Treppe.
Der Dummling geht die Treppe hinunter.
Unten ist eine Tür.

Comment: The question arises from a non-standard representation of compound words in easy language. As *Falltür* any dictionary can resolve this.

Comment: @guidot Why did you close this question? Leichte Sprache ist genauso Deutsch wie ein Dialekt oder Jugendsprache, und Fragen dazu sind doch erlaubt.

Comment: Rusland, that story is written in [Leichte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leichte_Sprache), a simplified variant of German created to help people with language disabilites better understand written texts. *Leichte Sprache* is often used in publications by government agencies that are targeted at immigrants or people suffering from mental retardation. The Wikipedia article on Leichte Sprache explains the use of the Mediopunkt ([Interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct)).

Comment: @fluctuating psychosis: I agree it's German, in fact it's not even a dialect but a register. You might as well declare questions about colloquial German off-topic. But it is a simple dictionary lookup so closable for that reason. Questions are sometimes closed here for reasons that are, let's say, unclear, so you're right to ask about this. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to a mechanism to change the reason for closing after the question has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is written in so called "leichter Sprache" (easy language), which aims at being easily comprehensible for people with a reading disability and employs the "[mediopunkt](https://www.ndr.de/fernsehen/barrierefreie_angebote/leichte_sprache/Was-ist-Leichte-Sprache,leichtesprache374.html)" to show word boundaries in compound words.

The word in question is "[Falltür](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Falltuer)", and simply means "[Trapdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor)".

> Bedeutungen (2)
>
> - waagerecht aufklappbare, in Fußbodenhöhe über einer Keller- oder Bodentreppe angebrachte Tür
> - geheime Klapptür im Fußboden, durch die eine eintretende Person hindurchfallen soll

([Duden - Falltür](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Falltuer))

Comment: See also [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fallt%C3%BCr). I'm afraid, that the rendering is intentionally showing the word boundaries as in *Dorn.röschen*. This is explained as *Mediopunkt* [here](https://www.ndr.de/fernsehen/barrierefreie_angebote/leichte_sprache/Was-ist-Leichte-Sprache,leichtesprache374.html).

Comment: The rendering on that site is not "unfortunate", but intentional and helpful for people with reading disabilities. You are just not the target audience.